# WinRT BLE BluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync unreachable Bluetooth 5

Tags: .net, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-runtime

I have a.NET V4.72 Application with Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts V10.0.22621.2 to access WinRT Bluetooth Low Energy API.

It works ok with BLE 4.2 devices, but when I try to make it work with BLE 5.2 devices, it just doesn't work properly.
I can successfully scan for, and pair with BLE 5.2 devices, but when I try to establish a connection by the uncached BluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync method, I always get unreachable error.

I had also tried with the provided example UWP ble samples, but with no success - the behavior is exactly the same.

What is causing this?

**PC:**

- Windows 10 Pro
- Version 21H1

Comment: Have you checked your device support https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-bluetooth-version-is-on-my-pc-f5d4cff7-c00d-337b-a642-d2d23b082793

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier, It says bluetooth specification 4.0 - I already knew that, but isn't bluetooth 5 supposed to be backward compatible with 4.0, otherwise it would be very bad design?

Comment: Do you have a Bluetooth adapter that supports Bluetooth 5.0? If you have, try to use the Bluetooth adapter on your windows device and try to connect to the Bluetooth 5.0 device. If using the Bluetooth adapter could let your windows device connect to the Bluetooth 5.0 device successfully, then the issue should be related to the hardware.

Comment: If the Bluetooth adapter doesn't work either, there might be an issue with the API. Please try to use the `system's built-in Bluetooth function` from **Setting** to connect to the Bluetooth 5.0 device to see if the built-in Bluetooth could work.